# URL for targeting in horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: php, html, css

I tried to create a link witch goes to two div's in once. I like to go for example to #item4 and then directly to #item4_section10.

here's an example:

```
<a href="index3.php?category=manage_team_teacher2.php&id_team=<?= $row['id_team'];?>#item4#item4_section10">manage</a>
```

div with id #item4 is horizontal and div with id item4_section10 vertical. if i go directly to item4_section10 this destroy the style of my page.

im new and i need your help.. thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your anchor `display: block` and after that you can give it a height and width and style your divs in it with `float` or `inline-block` or as you wish.

Comment: Can you give me an example please??